# JSON Path according to specific date

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following array of JSON objects
There ist one for each week.

```
[
  {
    "valutakode": "EUR",
    "valutabeskrivelse": "EURO",
    "valutakurs": "10,390",
    "omregningsenhet": 1,
    "fomdato": "2022-10-31",
    "tomdato": "2022-11-06"
  },
  {
    "valutakode": "EUR",
    "valutabeskrivelse": "EURO",
    "valutakurs": "10,180",
    "omregningsenhet": 1,
    "fomdato": "2022-11-07",
    "tomdato": "2022-11-13"
  }
]
```

I need the object that corresponds with the current week.
Is there an option to achive this using jsonpath?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this jsonpath

```
$[?(@.fomdato== '2022-11-07')]
```

or

```
$[?(@.fomdato == '2022-11-07' &&  @.tomdato == '2022-11-13')]
```

You will have to figure what is the first or the last date of  weeek of current date and convert it to string yyyy-mm-dd

I don't know what language are you using, but IMHO maybe it would be much easier to parse your json and use Date format to find the right object.

Comment: Yeees, it works BUT i want to use now() to get the right one. So the jsonpath should look somehow similar to [?(now() > toDate(@.fomdato, 'yyyy-MM-dd') && now() < toDate(@.todato, 'yyyy-MM-dd')]

Comment: It  has nothing to do with jsonPath, you have to convert Date() to yyy-mm-dd and use it as it is my answer. It is a different question. Google to find the example, or post a question how to convert data. There a lot of examples, I am not a free coder to do it for you.

Comment: That was exactly my question: Is there a way get the currently (now() ) correct object of the above objects using jsonpath.
When I got you right, it is not possible with jsonpath. I would need to do it in a programming lanuage of my choice, right?

Comment: @ChristianRockrohr It is possible with jsonpath. I don't know what language you use. Almost any language has jsonpath. You just need to convert current date to string.